# Is onCleared guarranteed to be called on a ViewModel in android?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

Can I safely put code to persist viewmodel data in the viewmodel's `onCleared` method? Would that guarrantee that the viewmodel's data will be put in persistant storage if the app is killed or finished for any reason or are there cases where `onCleared` may not be called?

Comment: You should generally save any data you want to persist as soon as possible (or within reasonable period). If user force stops the app no callbacks are guaranteed to be called.

Comment: @Pawel should I be worried about the inefficiency of updating a database incrementally with many queries as opposed to doing one batch insert before the view goes out of scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> are there cases where onCleared may not be called?

At minimum, it would be the cases where `onDestroy()` on an `Activity` may not be called. That includes:

- An unhandled exception
- The user clicking "Force Stop" on your app's screen in the Settings app
- Some cases where the system terminates your process in the background (specifically, where the need for system RAM is urgent, such as to handle an incoming call, and your app's process "draws short straw" to be terminated)

So, *usually* `onCleared()` is called, but it is not guaranteed.