# How can I check the app is freshly opened in the device (i.e) Already installed app is freshly opened in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to know the app is freshly opened in the device after the install. User may opened the app in the device around 12:00 pm and then the user closed and clears the cache.

Again opened the app around 4:00 p.m. (i.e) it is not from background. Only fresh opens of app.

How can I check this.

Note: The sharepref already available are to check the first open only. Not opening like this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need.

1. Do you want to differentiate the first opening of the app from subsequent ones even if the cache has been cleared?

2. Do you want to differentiate if the application was opened from cold boot or if it was just a state change from background to foreground?

Comment: I need to know [2] cold boot and also the [3] app is from background to foreground

Comment: @sejn, I'm also still confused, even after your response :c But for the background-foreground part you can add a lifecycle observer to the app class, override there onStart()/onStop() to get this change, would that work for your needs?

Comment: @PineapplePie If I add the LifecycleObserver it crash while freshly install in my mainactivity

Comment: @sejn it's not the observer that is crashing the app, it's rather something in your code inside of it. What are the first couple of lines in the crash stack trace?

Comment: @PineapplePie I need the three cases to check. When the user is install the app I not need to show the Ad for the user. When the user freshly opens the in n number of times  means cold start need to show the ad. If the user comes from background to foreground need to show the AppOpen ads. Here I have used sharedpreferences to check the first install of the app.  But the background to foreground got crash if I opens the AppOpen on cold start.I am using the AppOpen Applovin ads

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know the app is freshly opened in the device after the install.

This info should be tied to the application lifecycle (task stack), something like the `Application` class.

Unfortunately, we can't rely on the app destruction to determine that on the next launch of the app; so we can't use a permanent storage for that; because there is no such `onDestroy()` callback in the Application class to initialize that storage to the default value, and also activity's lifecycle destruction callbacks are not reliable as well; they can be silently destroyed when the system kills the app process to reclaim resources; i.e., [`onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called).

Same wise, ViewModel `onCleared()` is called when the app's process get killed, but also there are [possibilities that it doesn't get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66733829/is-oncleared-guarranteed-to-be-called-on-a-viewmodel-in-android).

But, instead we can use static variables for that; the fact is that static variables keep their values as long as their classes are kept in memory, and reinitialized to the default values when those classes are lost from the memory. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900456/lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-android).

The application class is a typical class to associate it to the app process lifecycle; and it's the most candidate class to live much in memory.

So, we'd do something like:

```
class MyApp: Application() {

    companion object {
        var isNewLaunch = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Then change this variable in `onCreate()` of the very first activity:

```
...
override onCreate() {
    if (MyApp.isNewLaunch) {
        // This is new launch
        MyApp.isNewLaunch = false
    }
}
```

If the app is left in the background and kept in memory, then when `onCreate()` get called, the assigned value is preserved, and the `if` condition won't be met.

Make sure to use `MyApp` as your application class in the manifest:

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
```

**Side Effect:**
One thing to take care of in this approach when there are parts of your app able to [save their state](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states); some views are able to save part of the their states automatically or developers can do that by overriding their [`onSaveInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)), activity's `onSaveInstanceState` or using ViewModel [`SavedStateHandle`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-savedstate); on those cases when the user leaves the app in background, and later on, the system destroys the app's process; the system tries to keep the state to be present on the next launch to the user, which probably is not the launch window of the app, and so the user can think of it as non-fresh open of the app, although it is definitely as a fresh open, because the app's process already destroyed and MyApp's static field is initialized to the default.

In that case, if you want to handle that as a non-fresh open, then you have to save some variable in the potential parts of your app that can save the sate; typically in `onSaveInstanceState` or ViewModel `SavedStateHandle`, and manipulate the condition to something like:

```
if (MyApp.isNewLaunch && !sateSaved) {
    // This is new launch
    MyApp.isNewLaunch = false
}
```

Or simply `savedInstanceState` would be checked in `onCreate()` callback of those activities:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (MyApp.isNewLaunch && savedInstanceState == null) {
        // This is new launch
        isNewLaunch = false
    }
}
```

Comment: isNewLaunch is a global variable, will it be true again after the memory is collected and the app is relaunched again?

Comment: @FrancisBacon Already that was mentioned and handled in the *Side Effect* section

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether an app is freshly opened on a device, you can employ various strategies. One common approach is to use SharedPreferences to store a flag indicating the first launch of the application. Here's an example in Kotlin Using **sharePreference**:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    if (isFirstRun()) {
        // Perform actions for the first launch
        // For example, initialize settings, load initial data, etc.

        // Set the flag to indicate that the app has been opened
        setFirstRunFlag()
    } else {
        // Perform actions for subsequent launches
    }
}

private fun isFirstRun(): Boolean {
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)
}

private fun setFirstRunFlag() {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply()
}
}
```

**Application Lifecycle:**

```
import android.app.Application

class MyApp : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    // Perform actions for the first launch
    // For example, initialize settings, load initial data, etc.
}
}
```

**Remember, the second approach executes when the application starts for the first time after installation or after the system process is killed. It may not differentiate between fresh installation and updates.**

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for but you can simulate a fresh app install by clearing the app's `cache` & `storage` which also clears the shared prefs.